# Is it possible to create Android live wallpapers using cocoonjs?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, cocoonjs

As per the question title, is there a way to implement an Android live wallpaper using CocoonJS? Either as a standalone app or as an additional service of an existing app, it doesn't matter. I can't seem to find any evidence at all that this is possible, although there doesn't seem to be any technical reason for it.

Comment: have a look http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been developing games with cocoonjs and I do not know of any API call to set a wallpaper.
Here you can see what you can do with the cocoonjs javascript API:
http://doc.ludei.com/3.0.5/

At the moment you can not add any more functionality than this API provides.
Nevertheless, there are plans for the future to make it possible to write own plugins :)

Regards